Eevee lights are not rendered correctly
i have a project in blender, i want to render it, but lights are not rendering correctly
Video of the issue: web.unideb.hu/imdd/videos/2024-11-21 00-57-20.mp4
My project: GRAF.RENDSZ
Download vanfoldis.blend
Thanks for any help

In your compositing nodes, Mix value of Glare node is set to 1. This means, you only get the glow without the original image.
Solution : set Mix to 0. You'll have the glow above the original image. To summarize :

Mix = -1 : you only get the original image
Mix = 0 : you get the original image with the glow
Mix = 1 : you only get the glow


thank you bro, you saved my uni project <3

@fineman Even better (I would not call it "advanced" though): leave Mix at 1 and use a Mix Color node set to Add to add the glow to the original image. This way you can control with the mix factor how much or how faint the glow is even with lower Threshold values. Of course reducing could be done by setting the Glare node's Mix to values below 0. But something which you can only do separately with a Mix Color node is adding with a factor higher than 1 if you think the glow is not bright enough. Or you can create different glow effects and combine them with multiple Add nodes.

@GordonBrinkmann thank you, i will try it :D
